# Name for circuit with multiple paths with aim of reducing inductance

Tags: layout, high-frequency, inductance

Trying to find the best way of describing a circuit that uses multiple separate physical paths to reduce effect of inductance on by HF signals.

Is there a term for such?

Comment: "parallel return paths"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's well understood that parallel inductances present a lower effective inductance. An engineer would call such a circuit simply "parallel", or since this is usually done with capacitors, "parallel capacitors", and the aim of reducing inductance is obvious.

Incidentally, it also increases capacitance, but arguably that's the same thing: making the [reactance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance) at some frequency of interest more capacitive, or equivalently, less inductive.